# Requiring web redirects for downloads in games

Tags: download

I've noticed that several game suffer from poor download speeds (<10Kb/s) when you don't use a web redirect (an apache,iis,... server), is there a programmatic reason for this that I don't see or is it for other reasons I'm missing.

It's been assumed that this is intended to not bog down the server but I'm looking to see if there is a less obvious (code) based reason.

Comment: Huh? Downloads in games? I'm mildly confused... Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: @Oli: I assume Unkwntech means stuff like maps or addons which are automatically downloaded in FPSs.

Comment: Well that was my first thought - but how do redirects factor into that at all? They're (usually) plain HTTP downloads...

Comment: Some games support direct download from the game server itself, instead of a standalone http server.

Comment: @heeen this is true but typically when this happens the download speeds are capped very low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three reasons, all linked.

1. Real web servers serve static content better. Fact. They're optimised for standard download-style traffic and separating that jazz from core game server code makes a lot of sense to a lot of developers. Plus they tend to use comparatively fewer resources and have higher levels of flexibility than a custom-made HTTP server.
2. Moving HTTP downloads off the game server keeps those important CPU cycles doing what you want them to: letting people frag the hell out of each other... If you can shuffle off the non-critical traffic to another, cheaper and/or clustered server, you keep your game playing smoothly.
3. As I hinted above, you can cluster or CDN the HTTP traffic, something you can't do (for fairly obvious reasons) with the game servers. This would only really apply on really busy networks but it's a good way to manage your traffic if you're dealing with a lot of potential downloads and they're all mission-critical.

Some game servers do handle it themselves, but, as you've noticed, most do it at a nauseatingly slow rate, again for the second reason above: resources. Bandwidth is almost as important as CPU, so uploads are heavily limited rate to keep players in the game going at top speed.